# Feasible Streaming Suggestions | Is it possible to use Apache Nifi + Apache Beam (on Flink Cluster) with Real Time Streaming Data

Tags: apache-flink, apache-nifi, apache-beam, data-pipeline

So, I am very very new to all the Apache Frameworks I am trying to use. I want your suggestions on a couple of workflow design for an IoT streaming application:

1. As we have NiFi connectors available for Flink, and we can easily use Beam abstraction over Flink. Can I use NiFi as the dataflow tool to drive data from MiNiFi to Flink Cluster (here store it in-memory or something) and then use Beam Pipeline to process the data further.
2. Is there any NiFi connector for the beam ? If not can we do so? So, we directly stream data from NiFi to the Beam job (running on a Flink Cluster)

I am still in the early design phase, it would be great if we can discuss possible workarounds. Let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: Can you describe your use case a bit more?

Comment: I want to import data from Apache NiFi to Apache Beam (running on Flink Cluster- using the new Portable runner ) @TurkerTunali

Comment: It really depends on the specifics like data rate and volume. I have seen the general setups NiFi + Flink and Flink + Beam running fine in production, so the combination of the three might be well possible. Could you also add why you want to have Beam in this architecture?

Comment: beam is just for making pipelining easy and "pythonic" (i think Flink Python is still at a quite early stage). Can you please describe more - how can we use the combination (NiFi+Flink+Beam) without the NiFi & Beam connector (if we can compromise a bit on the processing) @ArvidHeise